# killall(1) equivalent system call or C library call

Tags: linux, system, libc, kill-process

I have to stop the earlier instances of processes before starting a new instance. For this i need to system call or a C library call.

Presently i use "system("killall name"). This works but I want to replace this with any equivalent system(2)/library(3) calls. What is the option?

Also to remove files from directory as in "system("rm -f /opt/files*")",
what would be the alternate library(3)/system(2) call?
Pleas note * in file names, remove all files with one call.

regards,
AK

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about 2nd part -  system(" rm -f  /tmp/files* ") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no general way to do it, as there is no general way to get the `pid` by its process name.

You have to collect the `pid`s of related processes and call the `int kill(pid_t pid, int signo);` function

At least you can try to check how its implemented by `killall` itself

---

A small addition from Ben's link, `killall` invokes following lines, i.e. collecting the `pid`s of related process by `find_pid_by_name` function, implementation of which can be found [here](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/find_pid_by_name.c)

```
pidList = find_pid_by_name(arg);
if (*pidList == 0) {
    errors++;
    if (!quiet)
        bb_error_msg("%s: no process killed", arg);
} else {
    pid_t *pl;

    for (pl = pidList; *pl; pl++) {
        if (*pl == pid)
            continue;
        if (kill(*pl, signo) == 0)
            continue;
        errors++;
        if (!quiet)
            bb_perror_msg("can't kill pid %d", (int)*pl);
    }
}
```

Comment: And getting the list of processes is quite simple to code in C on Linux : `readdir` the `/proc/` file system. Focus on the subdirectories with a name starting with a digit. `readlink` its `/proc/1234/exe` symlink (where 1234 is an example of digit-starting name).

Comment: Exactly, Erik Andersen has implemented the same way. http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/find_pid_by_name.c

Answer (score 2):

You can see the implementation in busybox here: http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/procps/kill.c

You can also link with busybox as a shared library and invoke its `kill_main` instead of launching a separate process.  It looks fairly well behaved for embedding like this -- always returns normally, never calls `exit()` -- although you may have difficultly getting error information beyond the return code.  (But you aren't getting that via `system()` either).

Comment: Yes, I need on busybox only for embedded system. Thanks.